# Safari version 14 pageshow - event.persisted always set to false

Tags: javascript, safari, reload, page-refresh, pageshow

I'm trying to reload a page on safari if the user presses the browser back button and if the event is persisted. My code works on ***safai version 15.6***. But when I try on ***safari version 14.1***, it never enters the if block, which means the event.persisted is always set to false. I've tried every possible solution I could find. Any help will be much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.search("Safari") >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Chrome") < 0) {
  window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
    //PREVIOUS VERSIONS DON'T PASS THE IF CHECK HERE
    if (event.persisted || performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === 'back_forward') {
      location.reload();
      alert("HI");
    }
  },false);
}
```